# store previous page path in http session

Tags: php, session, navigation, httpsession

As the application I'm building grows larger, there are time when I re-factor. Sometimes this breaks things. For example, the location the user gets directed to after submitting a form - or maybe canceling etc. An idea I had was to store the current page path (URL sans domain name) in the session. That way I can go back to the page the user came from, mimicking what happens when you close a dialog box on a desktop application. This would be much more flexible and easy to maintain. At least it seems that way.

The current changes I'm making will allow the user to navigate to the form from various places in the app. If the user is sent to a different page then s/he came from, s/he will become disoriented. I have 43 forms. This will soon increase to approximately 60.

Is this a bad idea for some reason I'm overlooking? Or is this a recommended approach?

[EDIT]

Please read the comments in the answer for a real reason:

"storing this in session can cause some issues on simultaneous requests"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't your target script know where the user came from? I think it should, since each target processes specific form that has specific location.

If no - you can pass `return_url` in the hidden form field.

Imho it is a bad practice to store url in the session.

Comment: Why doesn't it? Well, because I didn't tell it obviously. That is why I'm trying to come up with a solution. So (let's pretend I'm not using a framework), are you saying I should add a field to all of my forms for this?

Comment: @sims: you should add a field to the forms, that shown on multiple places and it is not possible to determine (calculate) where to redirect user back. For example: if you have a blog + comments for them, after you've posted a comment you know where to redirect user to, because you have `$blog_id` - so redirect user to `/blogs/$blog_id` url.

Comment: Yes, of course. That is obvious, and that is how I'm currently doing it. However, there are a few different ways one might navigate to a form. If the user is sent to a different page, then s/he will become disoriented. As I stated, the application is LARGE. I have 43 forms. This will soon increase to approximately 60. I think I'll add this comment to the question.

Comment: @sims: anyway, regardless the number of forms I think that the hidden field with back url is the best solution.

Comment: What is the exact reason why I should avoid the session for this? If I use the session, I could store the user's entire history. This is could prove useful in the future for studying user behavior, etc. I was wary of using the session for this myself, which is why I asked here. I'm trying to think of a reason, but I can't.

Comment: @sims: storing this in session can cause some issues on simultaneous requests. I prefer to not use session for things that can rely on the execution flow.

Comment: Aha. Yes, that is true. I hadn't thought about that.